# How do I reference new fields in same SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem is with 'con_relief' and 'total_ded', as they do not exist in the payroll table but have been set in previous lines. How do I reference these new fields in same SQL statement?

```
CREATE VIEW `assessement` AS

SELECT con_income,  
    (CASE
        WHEN con_income<304347.83 THEN (0)
        ELSE (200000+(0.2*con_income))
    END)
AS con_relief,

(con_relief+lap+nhis+nhf+pension+gratuity) AS 'total_ded',
(con_income-total_ded) AS 'chargeable'


FROM payroll;
```

Comment: @marc_s: I'd say the use of `\`` and the non-standard use of a string literal for an identifier clearly indicates MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Make it as a `Sub-select` the use the computed column in outer query

```
SELECT con_income,
        CASE
           WHEN con_income < 304347.83 THEN ( 0 )
           ELSE ( 200000 + ( 0.2 * con_income ) )
         END AS con_relief,
        CASE 
            WHEN con_income<304347.83 THEN (0) 
            ELSE (200000+(0.2*con_income)) 
        END + lap + nhis + nhf + pension + gratuity  AS 'total_ded',
        con_income - ( CASE WHEN con_income<304347.83 THEN (0) 
                            ELSE (200000+(0.2*con_income)) 
                        END + lap + nhis + nhf + pension + gratuity )  AS 'chargeable'
```

Another workaround is Create a `view` for subquery then use it.

**Note:** Nesting view will have performance issues

```
CREATE VIEW Sub_view
AS
  SELECT con_income,
         CASE
           WHEN con_income < 304347.83 THEN ( 0 )
           ELSE ( 200000 + ( 0.2 * con_income ) )
         END  AS con_relief,
         CASE WHEN con_income < 304347.83 THEN ( 0 ) 
              ELSE ( 200000 + ( 0.2 * con_income ) ) END 
              + lap + nhis + nhf + pension + gratuity AS 'total_ded'
  FROM   payroll

CREATE VIEW assessement
AS
  SELECT con_income,
         con_relief,
         con_relief + total_ded                  AS total_ded,
         con_income - ( con_relief + total_ded ) AS chargeable
  FROM   sub_view a
```

Comment: You shouldn't call the first sum total_ded, because it is not the total_det, but only part thereof. Call it total_ded_part for instance, and you will certainly spot an error you made (chargeable is incomplete.)

Comment: Thanks alot, let me try that out. I will let you know how it goes

Comment: It appears subqueries can't be used in view statement. Returned error "View's SELECT contains a subquery in FROM clause"

Comment: @AondohembaWayo - yeah you are right. Try now updated

Answer (score 0):

You cant use any selected fields data in another selected fields.

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW `assessement` AS
   SELECT 
       con_income,  
       (CASE
            WHEN con_income<304347.83 THEN (0)
            ELSE (200000+(0.2*con_income))
        END) AS con_relief,
      (con_relief + lap + nhis + nhf + pension + gratuity) AS 'total_ded',
      (con_income - (con_relief + lap + nhis + nhf + pension + gratuity) ) AS 'chargeable'
  FROM 
      payroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

The expressions in the SELECT clause are not evaluated in any specific order. You expect to have evaluated the first expression first, name it con_relief, then have the second expression evaluated using con_relief, etc. But that doesn't work. The second expression may be evelauted before or at the same time as the first, so the name con_relief is not guaranteed to exist. This is why you cannot declare names and use them in the same where clause. So either use the same expression again and again or select in steps.

Solution 1:

```
SELECT 
  con_income,  
  (CASE WHEN con_income<304347.83 THEN (0) ELSE (200000+(0.2*con_income)) END) AS con_relief,
  ((CASE WHEN con_income<304347.83 THEN (0) ELSE (200000+(0.2*con_income)) END)+lap+nhis+nhf+pension+gratuity) AS total_ded,
  (con_income-((CASE WHEN con_income<304347.83 THEN (0) ELSE (200000+(0.2*con_income)) END)+lap+nhis+nhf+pension+gratuity)) AS chargeable
FROM payroll;
```

Solution 2:

```
select 
  con_income, con_relief, total_ded,
  con_income - total_ded as chargeable
from
(
  select 
    con_income, lap, nhis, nhf, pension, gratuity, con_relief,
    con_relief + lap + nhis + nhf + pension + gratuity as total_ded
  from
  (
    select 
      con_income, lap, nhis, nhf, pension, gratuity, 
      case 
        when con_income < 304347.83 then 0
        else 200000 + (0.2 * con_income)
      end as con_relief
    from payroll
  ) p1
) p2;
```

BTW: Single quotes ' are for string literals not for alias names.